# how to parse generic case class fields using scala option parser?

Tags: scala, generics, shapeless

I have a case class includes around 20 fields , all of which are primitive types.

```
case class A( f1: String, f2: Int .....)
```

and I have to parse these fields all from command line (unfortunately). 
I can , but I really don't want to write this 20 times

```
opt[String]("f1") required() valueName "<f1>" action { (x, c) =>
    c.copy(f1 = x)
  } text "f1 is required"
//...repeat 20 times
```

I can obtain the field name and filed type through reflection, but I have no idea how to stuck those information to this call within a for loop

I can connect this with shapeless but I'm still not familiar with that and can this be done without shapeless ?

==

scala option parser => scopt

Comment: I suppose that by "scala option parser", you mean [scopt](https://github.com/scopt/scopt) ?

Comment: You will find yourself reinventing shapeless if you want to do this. You are looking for something like `LabelledGeneric`.

Comment: @Alec, reimplementing the wheels are totally acceptable, as long as I only have to write a short piece of code.

Comment: @zinking The issue is that you need macros somewhere along the line - you need some way of extracting the fields, their names, and their types. That requires either a lot of not-type-safe reflection or macros with some shapeless style type-level programming.

Comment: I can bear with not-type-safe reflection in this case.

Answer (score 3):

I just noticed you wanted no libraries like shapeless. If it's any consolation this is a library that will replace scala reflect macros eventually, so it's about as close as pure scala you'll get without reinventing the wheel.

I think I may have something that might help with this. It's a kind of heavy solution but I think it will do what you are asking.

This uses the fantastic scalameta (http://www.scalameta.org) library in order to create a static annotation. You will annotate your case class and this inline macro will then generate the appropriate scopt parser for your command line args.

Your build.sbt is going to need the macro paradise plugin as well as the scalameta library. You can add these to your project with.

```
addCompilerPlugin("org.scalameta" % "paradise" % paradise cross CrossVersion.full)
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.scalameta" %% "scalameta" % meta % Provided,
)
```

Once you have added those deps to your build you will have to create a separate project for you macros.

A complete SBT project definition would look like

```
lazy val macros = project
  .in(file("macros"))
  .settings(
    addCompilerPlugin("org.scalameta" % "paradise" % paradise cross CrossVersion.full),
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.scalameta" %% "scalameta" % "1.8.0" % Provided,
    )
   )
```

If the module itself is named "macros", then create a class and here is the static annotation.

```
import scala.annotation.{StaticAnnotation, compileTimeOnly}
import scala.meta._

@compileTimeOnly("@Opts not expanded")
class Opts extends StaticAnnotation {
  inline def apply(defn: Any): Any = meta {
    defn match {
      case q"..$mods class $tname[..$tparams] ..$ctorMods (...$paramss) extends $template" =>
        val opttpe = Type.Name(tname.value)
        val optName = Lit.String(tname.value)
        val opts = paramss.flatten.map {
          case param"..${_} $name: ${tpeopt: Option[Type]} = $expropt" =>
            val tpe = Type.Name(tpeopt.get.toString())
            val litName = Lit.String(name.toString())
            val errMsg = Lit.String(s"${litName.value} is required.")
            val tname = Term.Name(name.toString())
            val targ = Term.Arg.Named(tname, q"x")
            q"""
                opt[$tpe]($litName)
                  .required()
                  .action((x, c) => c.copy($targ))
                  .text($errMsg)
            """
        }
        val stats = template.stats.getOrElse(Nil) :+ q"def options: OptionParser[$opttpe] = new OptionParser[$opttpe]($optName){ ..$opts }"
        q"""..$mods class $tname[..$tparams] ..$ctorMods (...$paramss) {
            import scopt._
            ..$stats
        }"""
    }
  }
}
```

After that you will make your main module depend on your macros module. Then you can annotate your case classes like so...

```
@Opts
case class Options(name: String, job: String, age: Int, netWorth: Double, job_title: String)
```

This will then at compile time expand your case class to include the scopt definitions. Here is what a generated class looks like from above.

```
case class Options(name: String, job: String, age: Int, netWorth: Double, job_title: String) {
  import scopt._

  def options: OptionParser[Options] = new OptionParser[Options]("Options") {
    opt[String]("name").required().action((x, c) => c.copy(name = x)).text("name is required.")
    opt[String]("job").required().action((x, c) => c.copy(job = x)).text("job is required.")
    opt[Int]("age").required().action((x, c) => c.copy(age = x)).text("age is required.")
    opt[Double]("netWorth").required().action((x, c) => c.copy(netWorth = x)).text("netWorth is required.")
    opt[String]("job_title").required().action((x, c) => c.copy(job_title = x)).text("job_title is required.")
  }
}
```

This should save you a ton of boiler plate, and for anyone with more knowledge of inline macros please feel free to tell me how I could write this better, since I am not an expert on this.

You can find the appropriate tutorial and documentation about this at http://scalameta.org/tutorial/#Macroannotations I'm also happy to answer any questions you might have about this approach!

Comment: thanks, the reason I don't wanted shapeless is its requirement of compiler plugins as I am on scala 2.10.  put that aside, I thought only some generic and complicated function declaration should solve it, why it has to be that complicated ?

Comment: I understand. I assume you're using scala 2.10? If you aren't shapeless does't require any compiler plugins to function. I don't think it's that this is a particularly hard problem, it's just that this problem requires you generate new code at compile time, so thus the macro.

Comment: how did you actually conclude that this requires code generation ? I thought this could be achieved just at runtime.

Comment: @zinking, I don't think the statement `c.copy(f1 = x)`) can be generalise without some form of code generation.  The `f1` is named argument which must be known in compile time. And case class simply provide no way for you to update a field by index / name.  One workaround is use `Map` instead of case class.

Comment: It's not that code gen is explicitly needed, I'm sure you can do it as well via reflection. But Scala reflection you'll have to do a lot of error prone non-typesafe things in order to get it to work. That kind of defeats the purpose of scopt's type safety and your case class. If you have the case class at compile time then there is no reason to do it at runtime, you're opting for a slower, more error prone, non-typesafe approach unless you have some very strict or non-standards requirements it really isn't the best way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version implemented with runtime reflection only. While it's less elegant than a macro based solution, it only requires the scala-reflect.jar:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value
```

Code:

```
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def genericParser[T: TypeTag](programName: String): OptionParser[T] = new OptionParser[T](programName) {
  val StringTpe: Type = typeOf[String]

  val fields: List[MethodSymbol] = typeOf[T].decls.sorted.collect {
    case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor ⇒ m
  }

  val values = mutable.Map.empty[TermName, Any]

  /**
    * Returns an instance of a [[scopt.Read]] corresponding to the provided type
    */
  def typeToRead(tpe: Type): Read[Any] = (tpe match {
    case definitions.IntTpe ⇒ implicitly[Read[Int]]
    case StringTpe          ⇒ implicitly[Read[String]]
      // Add more types if necessary...
  }) map identity[Any]

  for (f ← fields) {
    // kind of dynamic implicit resolution
    implicit val read: Read[Any] = typeToRead(f.returnType)
    opt[Any](f.name.toString) required() valueName s"<${f.name}>" foreach { value ⇒
      values(f.name) = value
    } text s"${f.name} is required"
  }

  override def parse(args: Seq[String], init: T): Option[T] = {
    super.parse(args, init) map { _ ⇒
      val classMirror = typeTag[T].mirror.reflectClass(typeOf[T].typeSymbol.asClass)
      val constructor = typeOf[T].decl(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
      val constructorMirror = classMirror.reflectConstructor(constructor)
      val constructorArgs = constructor.paramLists.flatten.map(symbol ⇒ values(symbol.asTerm.name))

      constructorMirror(constructorArgs: _*).asInstanceOf[T]
    }
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
case class A(f1: String, f2: Int)

println(genericParser[A]("main").parse(args, A("", -1)))
```

A few things to take in consideration:

- The parameters are stored in a mutable Map when they are parsed. The case class conversion in performed in a final step using the class constructor (`copy` method is not involved).
- As a consequence, the initial value passed in the `parse` method is not used at all (but it should not matter since all arguments are required).
- You must tweak the code to support different types of arguments, acccording to your need (the types of your case class values). I only added `String` and `Int` (See the *Add more types if necessary...* comment).